# Use form_for for non-attribute values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, form-for

I have a form_for like so:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
```

I would like to submit a parameter that is not an attribute of the model

```
<%= f.text_field :label%>
```

I have a Label model (labels has_many :posts and posts has_many :labels) and in the create action of the posts_controller I want to create a new Label object based off the label text_field. With the above text_field I get:

```
undefined method `label'for #<Object>
```

How can I go about achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your attribute doesn't exist into database table, and still you want to use it, then you have specify that attribute into model by following way

```
attr_accessor :name, :email, :content
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try fields_for method for the creation of associated objects.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for @post.labels do |label| %>
    <%= label.text_field :name %>
    <%= label.text_area :description %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To display default number of labels you need to build the associated objects in the controller.

In your posts controller add

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  #To build 2 labels use
  2.times do
  @post.labels.build 
  end
end
```

To accept the nested attributes add below code in your Post model.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :labels
end
```

Someone posted this then deleted...